# unable to access ssh over wan (router refuse to grant access)

Tags: router, ssh, wireless-router

in past i was able to connect ssh over wan easily but now i cant connect to my modem/router over wan
i have D-link DSL-2890AL modem/router and i want to connect to my Linux laptop over wan via ssh so i setup ddclient i config it next i port forward port 22 in my modem but when i try to connect over wan my router refuse to connect here is ssh logs:

```
 ssh -v xxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dlinkddns.com
 OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
 debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
 debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
 debug1: Connecting to xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dlinkddns.com [x.xxx.xx.xxx] port 22.
 debug1: connect to address x.xx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection timed out
 ssh: connect to host korousharian3390.dlinkddns.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

i checked my external IP address with ssh debug log and it works perfect
i even enable ping request over wan and test it with my ddns address and it work perfect i don't know whats my problem.

I spent a lot of time solving this problem, and thanks for any suggestions and help

Answer (score 0):

A quick check on your host reveals that it responds to ping:

```
vesemir:~> ping -c 5 korousharian3390.dlinkddns.com
PING korousharian3390.dlinkddns.com (5.236.18.209) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 5.236.18.209 (5.236.18.209): icmp_seq=3 ttl=47 time=189 ms
64 bytes from 5.236.18.209 (5.236.18.209): icmp_seq=4 ttl=47 time=157 ms
64 bytes from 5.236.18.209 (5.236.18.209): icmp_seq=5 ttl=47 time=187 ms

--- korousharian3390.dlinkddns.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 3 received, 40% packet loss, time 4001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 157.354/178.397/189.965/14.908 ms
```

so there is something over there. nmap however doesn't find any responding ports there:

```
vesemir:~> nmap -Pn -p 22,80,443 korousharian3390.dlinkddns.com

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2019-07-30 18:22 CEST
Nmap scan report for korousharian3390.dlinkddns.com (5.236.18.209)
Host is up.
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp  filtered ssh
80/tcp  filtered http
443/tcp filtered https

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.02 seconds
```

(same story with longer default check).

There are quite a few possibilities why this is happening:

1. Your router is behind NAT (Carrier Grade NAT or CG-NAT) and the public IP address picked by DDNS is NOT your address but your providers address. If this is the case it's the end of the story (short of setting up your own VPS as a proxy).
2. This is old address of your router which has not been properly updated when it changed. In this case you probably would have to reboot the router (but consider this a workaround, not a solution).
3. Your router is not configured to perform the port forwarding to your Linux laptop.
4. Your router forwards traffic but your Linux laptop has firewall turned on and this is why you cannot connect.
5. If you have DHCP on you router/network - the IP address of your laptop might have changed. This will highly likely require change of your forwarding rule (my advice - use static IP or DHCP reservation for your laptop).

Comment: many thanks for your response tomek in these possibilities you wrote i think 1 must be it but 1 year ago i could connect to it  same way only one thing change since then i changed my ISP and thats all. all of my configs in laptop and router was not changed.

Comment: A year is A LOT of time. You should be able to see external address on the router interface and this should confirm your suspicion.

Comment: yes i did this too it not about only ddns why my router suddenly goes behind Nat i did not change any configuration to have this problem.